# Playng video file present in Local File System in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

How to play video present in local file system (ex:in res/a.3gp) using VideoView .
I need Sample code.
I am trying to play as below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class videoSample extends Activity {  
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
     String path="D:/mApp2/videoSample/res/drawable-hdpi/adf.mp4"; 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView01);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
        videoView.setVideoPath(path);   
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
        mediaController.show();
    }
}
```

I am getting error as Video cant be played.
Can any one help me in sorting out this issue?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please format your code as code, it's hard to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> String path="D:/mApp2/videoSample/res/drawable-hdpi/adf.mp4";

There is no D: drive in Android. Android is not Windows.

Answer (score 2):

i used this string and worked for me:

```
private String srcPath = "android.resource://com.myapp/raw/videofile";
```

then...

```
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(srcPath));
```

where com.myapp is the app main package

hope it helps!

Comment: note that you have to place your file in the raw folder into the resources

Comment: This works, I was having a similar problem and this fixed it right away. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Afaik it's not possible to play videos from the internal app storage, see
[Can a videoview play a video stored on internal storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038474/can-a-videoview-play-a-video-stored-on-internal-storage)

I faced similar issue and already searched about it.

http://www.anddev.org/multimedia-problems-f28/videoview-cannot-play-video-from-internal-storage-t16636.html

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a01d415c8e48e0d3

Workaround is to copy the video to sdcard temporarily and play it from there.