# Creating folder in internal Memory to save files and retrieve them later

Tags: android, memory, directory, internal

I want to make a folder in the Internal Memory in my application to store Audio Files,then check if the exist to do some operations.
How to make this folde, in which path, and how to retrieve these files again?

Comment: Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), then add some code to your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
File mydir = context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile"); //Getting a file within the dir.
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir); //Use the stream as usual to write into the file
```

For deleting a file from internal :

```
if (new File("path/to/file").delete()) {
  // Deleted
} else {
  // Not deleted
}
```

Comment: thanx ..i tried it,and  i saw the path in the Log(/data/data/com.packageName/app_mydir/audio.mp3)
But i want to play the audio but it keep showing me this error(android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method))

 
in the prepare Method

Comment: if(mp==null){
 mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {    mp.setDataSource("/data/data/com.packageName/app_mydir/audio.mp3");
           
           } 
       
       catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
   }
       
       
       if(mp != null && !mp.isPlaying()){
       try {
           mp.prepare();
       
            }

Comment: You wanna play audio during activity in the Internal Memory , Right ?

Comment: yeh...and by the way how can i delete these files from the memory if i won't use them anymore?

Comment: i found this solution...and it works fine...:)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833777/android-playing-resource-files-from-internal-storage-causes-mediaplayer-prepare

but i wanna know how can i delete these files?

Comment: Thanks alot Ali..:)
But do you know how can i check if the media file reach the end ??

Comment: What if I wanted to create a folder on application (only the first time). When saving the file, I would like to create a subfolder inside the already created folder. For example: On application load, I would like to create `com.mycompany.myapp` folder. Then, I would like to create another folder inside that, so, `com.mycompany.myapp\Folder1` and then `com.mycompany.myapp\Folder2` and so forth. Or is it recommended to create separate folder and not sub folder?