# Android Issues in playing audio file

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I have downloaded audio files from server and saved it using

```
/data/data/packagename/sounds/filename.mp3
```

Then if I play that audio using

```
.MediaPlayer mp= new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mp.setDataSource(PATH+"/"+fileName);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mp.start();
```

But it shows an error

```
MediaPlayer:start called in state 2
MediaPlayer:Error(-38,0)
MediaPlayer:Error(-38,0)
```

Whats the problem with it I searcheed a lot regarding this but no solution pls suggest any solutions

Comment: Log cat shows  MediaPlayer:start called in state 2
MediaPlayer:Error(-38,0)
MediaPlayer:Error(-38,0)

Comment: What are the contents of your `PATH`and `fileName` variables?

Comment: Path name-/data/data/packagename/sounds/,file name-filename.mp3

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code,

```
public void audioPlayer(String path, String fileName){
    //set up MediaPlayer    
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mp.setDataSource(path+"/"+filename.mp3);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start();
}
```

Comment: i tried above code, log cat errors, 05-28 18:44:46.933: W/System.err(21770): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
05-28 18:44:47.024: E/MediaPlayer(21770): start called in state 0
05-28 18:44:47.024: E/MediaPlayer(21770): error (-38, 0)
05-28 18:44:47.063: E/MediaPlayer(21770): Error (-38,0)

Comment: path means in where your audio file is located

Comment: PATH=/data/data/packagename/audio.mp3

Comment: but i have issue,that audio can't play,please solve my problem

Comment: Refer this previous post, i hope i may solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833777/android-playing-resource-files-from-internal-storage-causes-mediaplayer-prepare