# Can't get file from android cache directory

Tags: android, file, caching, audio, uri

I'm having a problem getting files from my Android application's cache folder. This is what I'm trying to to but doesn't work:

```
    File cacheDir = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir();
    myFile = File.createTempFile("filename", ".mp3", cacheDir);

    ...
    // Here I have to code to initialize the file
    ...

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "file.length = "+myFile.length());  // This logs correct info

    ...

    //File file = new File(myFile.getPath());
    //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "file.length() = "+file.length());  // This logs 0
    //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "file.name = "+file.getName());     // This is correct

    String fileURI = myFile.getPath();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileURI);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();             // This crashes
```

As you can see it seems the file doesn't contain anything. However I've tried to swap the two first lines with this piece of code and then it works.

```
    myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MYFOLDER/filename.mp3");
```

I haven't found any way to set my mediaPlayer without the URI and when I try to get the file from the URI it seems to be a problem.

Do you have solution to how I can get the file from the cache directory?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I managed to find a solution to this myself. First, I was able to "add content" to the file by changing createTempFile with this:

```
myFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "filename.mp3");
```

**Unfortunately**, seems you can't read files from this directory. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833777/android-playing-resource-files-from-internal-storage-causes-mediaplayer-prepare).

Therefore I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761305/android-mediaplayer-throwing-prepare-failed-status-0x1-on-2-1-works-on-2-2) post and I managed to solve it. Here is my final code:

```
     myFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "filename.mp3");

     ...

     Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_play);
     playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             play(myFile);
         }
     });

                    ...

        public void play(File f) {
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
                     ...
```

If you can't pass the file, then I can't help you. But please post solution when you find one.