# VideoView can play mp4 file in application data directory

Tags: android, android-videoview

While save mp4 file to /data/data/mypackage/files/my.mp4, then call VideoView's setVideoPath(); it can not work.

For the same file, if I save the file to /mnt/sdcard/my.mp4, then call the same VideoView's setVideoPath, it plays correctly.

Is there any way I can play mp4 file under /data/data/mypackage/files/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **MP** or **VideoView** uses a native player which **cannot access non-worldreadable files.**

So you have to options basically:

1) Make the created files world-readable

2) Open an input stream to the file in your program and just hand over the file descriptor to the media player:

```
FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
MediaPlayer pl = new MediaPlayer();
pl.setDataSource(fi.getFD());
pl.prepare();
pl.start();
```

Also look at this thread [VideoView/MediaPlayer doesn't play video from internal storage](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10197#makechanges) And find a **Custom VideoView** class code from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10197#makechanges) also look at this SO question [Can a videoview play a video stored on internal storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038474/can-a-videoview-play-a-video-stored-on-internal-storage)

Comment: How would you do this with just the VideoView though?