# Android - FileInputStream Error / Playing a local video

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, fileinputstream

Hosting the video online is not possible nor is using an SD card a realistic solution to my issue... Due to several factors such as the likely hood that the SD cards would disappear.

So I found this, and this says it's possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5475436/584994

But I can't seem to get the FileInputStream correct... Under the package explorer my file is located under AppName->res->drawable->overview_animatic.mp4

and the string I am passing to FileInputStream is "/res/drawable/overview_animatic.mp4" am I doing this incorrectly?

Does the solution in the above link no longer work?

Is there a better way to play an internal video?

Comment: Have you tried what was suggested in the top rated answer from this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028717/how-to-play-videos-in-android-from-assets-folder-or-raw-folder

Comment: It worked a treat. You should add it as an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the top answer for [How to play videos in android from assets folder or raw folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028717/how-to-play-videos-in-android-from-assets-folder-or-raw-folder) for an explanation of how to play a video from an application resource.