# VideoView vs MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player

Please tell me why this would work on with MediaPLayer and not in videoView? And how to make it work with a video view?

Videos are downloaded form an API and saved in this folder I created:

```
File mediadir = cw.getDir("tvr", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**VideoView**

```
final Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
// path = /data/data/com.foo.app/tvr/video.mp4
videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
videoView.start();
```

Error VideoView **Sorry, this Video cannot be player** and error (1, -2...)

**MediaPlayer --- THIS WORKS**

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);

 MediaPlayer pl = new MediaPlayer();
 pl.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
 pl.prepare();
 pl.start();
```

Answer (score 6):

The basic reason is the MODE_PRIVATE, which disallow VideoView and MediaPlayer from playing non-World Readable files, *unless you pass the FD* as you have.

[Here's a more detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038474/can-a-videoview-play-a-video-stored-on-internal-storage)

Comment: @Harry, is my answer not clear enough to be accepted? If it is, please do so as I need the karma points! :)