# Unsolved: Android audio recording using example from Google

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I'm learning how to record audio using http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html#example

Everything works fine, but I want to switch:

```
mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
```

to

```
mFileName = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
```

but I get this error

```
08-19 15:51:44.212: E/MediaPlayer(6654): error (1, -2147483648)
08-19 15:51:44.212: E/AudioRecordTest(6654): prepare() failed
```

I tried to log my new code (to make sure that I'm using a valid path).

### NOTE:

This **works** on my Samsung Galaxy, but **doesn't work** on my Nexus One. I want this to work on 2.x, 3.x, and 4.x

**Update:**
I added a log in startRecording():

```
mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        Log.e("LOG", mFileName);
```

The output of that log is:

```
08-22 12:28:40.112: E/LOG(9666): /data/data/com.example.testrecorder/files/audiorecordtest.3gp
```

Tried logging the exception:

```
  private void startPlaying() {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed", e);
        }
    }

08-22 13:08:03.158: E/MediaPlayer(10093): error (1, -2147483648)
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093): prepare() failed
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093):   at com.example.testrecorder.MainActivity.startPlaying(MainActivity.java:51)
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093):   at com.example.testrecorder.MainActivity.onPlay(MainActivity.java:41)
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093):   at com.example.testrecorder.MainActivity.access$1(MainActivity.java:39)
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093):   at com.example.testrecorder.MainActivity$PlayButton$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:113)
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9308)
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4333)
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-22 13:08:03.168: E/AudioRecordTest(10093):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post your code for MediaPlayer and MediaRecorder?

Comment: I'm using the exact code from the example in the link.

Comment: can you system.out.println mFileName when you call 'mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);' ?

Comment: print what you get as the mFileName and check if that path is valid. Check on a real device, sometimes the emulator has errors on emulated storage.

Comment: Added a log, and it seemingly gives a valid path. Also, I'm checking on three devices. It works on 1/3 devices.

Comment: Have you checked that the `File` returned by `getFilesDir()` is present using `exists()`? Sometimes on a fresh install it is not present. Try a `mkdir()`.

Comment: In onCreate I added: `mFileName = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        Log.e("LOG", getFilesDir().exists()+"");` and it returns true.

Comment: Can you log the `IOException` you're getting instead of just `"prepare() failed"`? That might be more helpful.

Comment: Try `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Updated my question with the stacktrace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create a new `MediaPlayer` object, it's not really part of *your* app, it's part of the system. Because this is true, it can't read files in your app's private directory unless they are `WORLD_READABLE`. That's why it works with the external directory and not your internal one. Yes, that sounds ridiculous, I agree.

You should be able to get around this by creating a `FileDescriptor` and passing it to `MediaPlayer` that way:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFileName);
mPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
```

Note: **gtkandroid** gives [a more thorough explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5475436/752320), which I found through the [bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10197). If this works for you, I'd suggest you upvote his answer on the other question as well.

Comment: Hmm... a file  descriptor seems like a valid workaround. It is a bit ridiculous though, how it "is" your own app trying to access it's "own" data.

Comment: No argument from me there. You'd think that it would at least be consistent between `MediaPlayer`/`MediaRecorder`. Being able to write to a file and then denying read access seems a bit counterintuitive, to say the least.

Comment: Yep, thank you for your time. I appreciate it. Bounty can't be awarded for another 20+ hours... heh.

Answer (score 0):

So using that code, I had to move the creation of the filename outside of the Constructor and into `onCreate()`. The `Context` isn't valid yet so you should get an error on `getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    mRecordButton = new RecordButton(this);
    ll.addView(mRecordButton,
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            0));
    mPlayButton = new PlayButton(this);
    ll.addView(mPlayButton,
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            0));
    setContentView(ll);

    mFileName = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
}
```

Comment: Still get errors.
08-22 16:08:50.269: W/MediaRecorder(3530): mediarecorder went away with unhandled events
08-22 16:08:52.259: E/MediaPlayer(3530): error (1, -2147483648)
08-22 16:08:52.259: E/AudioRecordTest(3530): prepare() failed