# FileProvider - use default InternalStorage folder, filePaths ambiguity

Tags: android

It says in the documentation:

> A FileProvider can only generate a content URI for files in
>   directories that you specify beforehand. To specify a directory,
>   specify the its storage area and path in XML, using child elements of
>   the  element. For example, the following paths element tells
>   FileProvider that you intend to request content URIs for the images/
>   subdirectory of your private file area.
>
> ```
>  <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>  <files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>
>  ... </paths>
> ```

What If I dont want to use a subdirectory, but the default internalstorage directory?

2. This is an example file paths xml file from the documentation:

   < paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   ```
   <files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>

   <files-path name="my_docs" path="docs/"/>
   ```

When I use it in my project, I get "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix"

Should I add it? Is it possible that the documentation has a mistake in it, or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What If I dont want to use a subdirectory, but the default internalstorage directory?

Leave off the `path` attribute.

> When I use it in my project, I get "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix"

I have no idea what is giving you this message. If it is an IDE, it is probably a bug in the IDE. Technically, we don't even need the namespace declaration, though [my sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) has it as well.

> Should I add it?

No. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) works fine without it.

Comment: So it should just be <paths>
    <files-path name="whatever"/>
</paths>, then?

Comment: @J.K.: Correct. Personally, I went with `stuff` rather than `whatever`. :-)

Comment: one last thing - where would I need to use the name I provide in files-path (in my case whatever, in your case stuff)?

Comment: Why is your FileProvider called LegacyCompatFileProvider instead of  android.support.v4.content.FileProvider?

Comment: @J.K.: Because I subclassed `FileProvider`. There are some unfortunate developers out there that assume all `content://` `Uri` values must be from `MediaStore` and try using a `_data` column that isn't there. `LegacyCompatFileProvider` overrides `query()` and employs a `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper` to provide an empty `_data` column, which improves compatibility with some of these apps. In your case (playing videos via Android media APIs), none of that should be needed.

Comment: can you take a look at this one? I am struggling a lot with the FileProvider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896130/fileprovider-crash-npe-attempting-to-invoke-xmlresourceparser-on-a-null-string