# FileProvider crash - npe attempting to invoke XmlResourceParser on a null String

Tags: android

This is a part of my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.asd"
    android:versionCode="118"
    android:versionName="118" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


    <application
        android:name="com.example.asd.AsdApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
        android:theme="@style/AsdTheme" >
        ...

        <provider
            android:name="com.example.asd.database.hq.ContentProviderDB"
            android:authorities="ourContentProviderAuthorities" >
        </provider>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.asd.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>

       ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the filepaths file in raw/xml/filepaths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="media"/>
</paths>
```

I download a video from internet and save it to internal storage this way:

```
public static boolean saveInputStreamToInternalStorageFile(Context context, String filename, byte[] dataToWrite, Context ctx) {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + filename);

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(dataToWrite);
        oos.close();
        return true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I try to use it like so:

```
private void playVideoFromDeviceWithWorkaround(String fileName) {

    File newFile = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);
    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.asd", newFile);

    try {
        vvVideoFullscreen.setVideoURI(contentUri);
        showMediaControls = true;
        playVideo();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        playVideoFromNetwork();
    }

}
```

At this line:

```
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.asd", newFile);
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:560)
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:534)
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:376)
```

Comment: "This is the filepaths file" -- where exactly in your project is this file?

Comment: raw/xml/filepaths.xml

Comment: in authorities I have .provider, appended to app package, but when calling getUriForFile, I dont append .provider. maybe tthats it, Im testing right now

Comment: Yes that was the problem

Answer (score 272, accepted):

The problem was that in Manifest I had this line:

```
android:authorities="com.example.asd.fileprovider"
```

and when calling getUriForFile I was passing:

```
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.asd", newFile);
```

So changed from `"com.example.asd"` to `"com.example.asd.fileprovider"` and it worked

Comment: Thanks worked for me. First I was doing like this.  android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider   Now i changed it to com.memecreator.fileprovider my actual package name

Comment: Agree with @Rayyan, Best to use `android:authorities="${applicationId}"` always; code will never be at fault.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me... I'm getting null pointer exception still after checking to make sure this is correct.

Answer (score 44):

You can do this without hardcoding the package name with an additional benefit of being able to run multiple variants on the same device (think `release` and `debug` with `applicationIdSuffix`, see [these issues](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Can%27t+install+because+provider+name%22+%22is+already+used+by%22)):

Based on `FileProvider.java:560`

```
final ProviderInfo info = context.getPackageManager()
        .resolveContentProvider(authority, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
final XmlResourceParser in = info.loadXmlMetaData( //560
        context.getPackageManager(), META_DATA_FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS);
```

you were using the wrong `authority` and it didn't find the `ContentProvider` (`info == null`).

Change your manifest to (`${applicationId}` will be replaced by Manifest Merger)

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.share"
```

and

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".share", result);
```

*The `.share` suffix is optional, in case you have a real `ContentProvider` which is better to have the package name as the authority.*

Comment: Worked for me...I have used the last two lines and its work perfectly..Thanks

Answer (score 23):

In my case, I got the error because the

```
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
```

was being imported from

```
import android.support.v4.BuildConfig;
```

So the string it returned was `"android.support.v4"` instead of my project package name. Check out the import file is from your `import project.Buildconfig` and not another. Example:

```
import com.example.yourProjectName.BuildConfig;
```

Finally, in `<provider>` tag in Manifest I have `android:authorities="${applicationId}"` to always get my project package name as the authority

```
<manifest>
   ..
   ..
   <application>
    ..
    ..
       <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/ruta_fileprovider" />
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what is  android:resource="@xml/ruta_fileprovider"

Comment: @AnantaPrasad <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
</paths>

Answer (score 5):

First, be sure that you provider `android:authorities` does not conflict with your other providers. Besides that you may choose any name for the last part of its name: "provider", "fileprovider" etc., but app crashes when there are more than one `android:authorities` listed, while documentation states that it allows multiple values listed.

`file://` scheme is now not allowed to be attached with Intent on targetSdkVersion >= 24 (Android N 7.0), only `content://` is always passed for all devices (Android 5, 6 and 7). But we encountered that Xiaomi breaks this Google convention and sends `file://`, hence `data.getData().getAuthority()` gives empty string.

```
final String uriScheme = currentUri.getScheme();
if ("content".equals(uriScheme)) {
    // getting full file path (works with some providers, i.e. Gallery)
    path = FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), currentUri);
    if (path != null) {
         currentFile = new File(path);
    }
} else if ("file".equals(uriScheme)) {
    // in a rare case we received file:// in currentUri, we need to:
    // 1. create new File variable from currentUri that looks like "file:///storage/emulated/0/download/50044382b.jpg"
    // 2. generate a proper content:// Uri for it
    currentFile = new File(currentUri.getPath());
    String authority = data.getData().getAuthority();
    if (authority != null && !authority.isEmpty()) {
        currentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), authority, currentFile);
    }
} else {
    // throw exception
}
```

Also, the bug when `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` resulted in crash `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example/files/attachments/image.jpg` was fixed in Android Support Library v24.2.0. The problem was that FileProvider.java did not see external-path folders.

Answer (score 1):

If you're building your AUTHORITY at runtime using `BuildConfig` make sure you use the full class name including your package name.

Bad:

`final String AUTHORITY = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider";`

Good:

`final String AUTHORITY = com.mycompany.myapp.BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider";`

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me.

```
mUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    fileObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did to fix the issue. I gave fully qualified name in android:name. It works in android 6,7,8

```
    <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.opener.provider" 
        android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" 
        android:name="io.github.pwlin.cordova.plugins.fileopener2.FileProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Comment: can you please share your code for share file using file provider from internal directory ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try it:

```
  Context context = PostAdapter.this.activity;
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder();
                    stringBuilder2.append(PostAdapter.this.activity.getPackageName());
                    stringBuilder2.append(".provider");
                    Uri uri;
                    uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,stringBuilder2.toString(), newFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
Uri fileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), getActivity().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", file);
```