# Android install apk error on Android N

Tags: java, android, xml

Question:I failure when i try install apks on Android N.
This part is Error info.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser
>   android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:583)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:557)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:399)
>                                                                              at
>   me.hades.androidsafer.utils.SystemUtils.installApk(SystemUtils.java:59)
>                                                                              at
>   me.hades.androidsafer.utils.SystemUtils.installApk(SystemUtils.java:51)
>                                                                              at
>   me.hades.androidsafer.activity.SplashActivity$2.completed(SplashActivity.java:154)
>                                                                              at
>   com.liulishuo.filedownloader.FileDownloadMessenger.handoverMessage(FileDownloadMessenger.java:341)
>                                                                              at
>   com.liulishuo.filedownloader.FileDownloadMessageStation$UIHandlerCallback.dispose(FileDownloadMessageStation.java:169)
>                                                                              at
>   com.liulishuo.filedownloader.FileDownloadMessageStation$UIHandlerCallback.handleMessage(FileDownloadMessageStation.java:160)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

This part is Manifest.xml

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="me.hades.androidsafer.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>

    </provider>
```

This part is @xml/file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>

    <external-path path="Download/" name="Download" />
    <external-files-path name="Download" path="Download/" />
</paths>
```

installApk() function:

```
public static void installApk(Context context,File file) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileProvider", file);
            intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        } else {
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        }
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

How i do to fix this error?
My English not well. Thinks

Comment: It looks like `context` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896130/fileprovider-crash-npe-attempting-to-invoke-xmlresourceparser-on-a-null-string) might be it shall be helpful for you. Problem is in your File Provider.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem recently, and in the end I got it to work with the following code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
                    intent.setData(apkUri);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                }
```

Try using: Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the code you included in your question is that your `authority` string parameter (passed into `FileProvider.getUriForFile`) doesn't quite match. In your AndroidManifest.xml file you specified a suffix of `.fileprovider` but in your `installApk` method you specified a suffix of `.fileProvider`. It's case sensitive and needs to match.