# How can I access whatsapp/media directory in android 11 (Scoped storage)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-11

I have an app that access status folder in whatsapp/media directory.

But on android 11 my app is not working due to android 11 scoped storage.

Is there a way to access statuses folder in whatsapp/media directory ?

Comment: SAF will do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read WhatsApp media path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399457/how-to-read-whatsapp-media-path)

Answer (score 4):

In Android 11 the path has changed to /Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/media

Comment: Recently I checked the path but still its there in older path. Not sure is it for particular version only ?

Comment: How can I create that kind of folder

Answer (score 3):

**I think it might be work.**

```
String mString=  Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<=30  ? "WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses":"Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses";
```

Comment: Recently I checked the path but still its there in older path. Not sure is it for particular version only ?

Answer (score 2):

Google Play changed their policy in All file access permission.

Here I mentioned below the github link where he used file access for Whatsapp status Downloader but the problem is if you publish it on playstore means it won't work they will reject your app so you can find the solution for that.
https://github.com/GauthamAsir/WhatsApp_Status_Saver

Comment: It has a second branch called `android 11`, it should work